# Should I inject python built-in libraries like os or json (via factory class) to make my code unit testable?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, refactoring

I am refactoring my entire project to make it unit testable by injecting dependencies via the constructor of classes. This eliminates instances where objects were getting instantiated in a standalone fashion (this isn't unit testable since I no longer have a direct control over these objects). I am confused if I should inject python built-in modules like os or json.

I have created a single factory which has static methods which return either classes or objects. This makes dependency injection possible.

Initially :

```py
import json

def do_something(self):
    object_a = UserClassA()
    some_value = json.dumps({})
```

Currently :

```py
def do_something(self, factory_object):
    object_a = factory_object.get_user_class_a()
    some_value = factory_object.get_json().dumps({})
```

The latter implementation makes it unit testable. Both the custom class A and built-in module json has been taken care of. But, is injecting json in this way the proper way to make code unit testable? Or is it better to patch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR : you're going way over the top here !!!**

While using dependency injection makes sense for some use cases, your approach here is a bit extreme to say the least. Are you planning on providing DI even for builtin types and functions ?-)

Python is dynamic - very dynamic - so it's quite easy to monkeypatch a module's top-level names with whatever you want, manually or [using `mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

wrt/ your example, keep the original code as is:

```
import json

class UserClassA():
   # ....

class Foo(object):
    def do_something(self):
        object_a = UserClassA()
        some_value = json.dumps({})
```

and in your tests, monkeypatch or mock `yourmodule.json` and/or `yourmodule.UserClassA` - and keep DI for when it makes sense *for normal usage* (IOW, don't add DI only for unitesting, unless you have a special case where the monkeypatch/mock solution is really really really inconvenient, but that's quite rare actually).

Writing your code so it's easier to unittest (by favoring pure functions, keeping functions and classes well focused on a single responsability etc) is a good move  - done right it usually results in code that's also easier to read and maintain. **BUT** unittests are not the goal - the goal is a program that is (by order of importance) 1/ correct (do what it should do), 2/ robust (properly handles corner cases and unexpected situations without corrupting your precious data nor producing wrong results), and 3/ maintainable.

Having a good unittest coverage helps with those three goals, but only to the extent that it doesn't turn your code base into an overengineered, unreadable mess with useless levels of indirection that actually serve no other mean than pleasing the "agile" zealots. When in doubt, [check this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Oh and yes: unittests don't come for free - you have to write them, but, more important, you have to *maintain* them when your code changes. So don't fall into the "100% unittest coverage" trap either, you mostly want to test (automate tests for, I mean) the critical stuff.